# Solve for $x$: $x^4+2x^3-x-1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, quartics

Solve for  $x$:

$$x^4+2x^3-x-1=0$$

My try ;

$$x^4+2x^3-x-1=(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+px+q)=0$$
But I cannot go further!!!

Comment: You can certainly set $a=d=1$.  Then if you're looking for quadratics with integer coefficients, you might as well set $c=1$ and $q=-1$.  That leaves you with just $b$ and $p$ to check for.

Comment: @Travis.yeah is correct

Comment: @BarryCipra It happens that no quadratics with integer coefficients exist in the present case.

Comment: @Did, I was mainly responding to the OP's "I cannot go further."

Comment: That was a good question and it received a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$x^4+2x^3-x-1=\left(x^2+x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}$$
and the rest is smooth.

We can get it by the following way.
$$x^4+2x^3-x-1=(x^2+x+k)^2-((2k+1)x^2+(2k+1)x+k^2+1)$$
for all value of $k$ and for $k=-\frac{1}{2}$ we'll get  a difference of squares.

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

Let $f (x)=x^4+2x^3-x-1$.
$f (0)=-1,f (1)=1,f (-2)=1$
there is at least one root in $(0,1) $ and

one in $ (-2,0)$.

$$f''(x)=12x^2+12x=12x (1+x)\geq 0$$

there are only two real roots.

Comment: "Hint" for what?

Answer (score -1):

$(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+px+q)=adx^4+(ap+bd)x^3+(aq+bp+cd)x^2+(bq+pc)x+cq$

Try to solve a,b,c,d,p,q

as 
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
ad=1\\ 
ap+bd=2\\ 
aq+bp+cd=0\\ 
bq+pc=-1\\  
cq=-1\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Comment: Did you try yourself, by any chance? How did it go?